# Rails - How can i get the users who like the story

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Hi have some objects in rails of Story, Likes And User

I want to create a "like" system as a social networks(facebook,google+, etc.)
Thing is the "Like" will be on the story and not on the user.

So i created a Like object [relationships] between stories and users

my objects look as below:

```
class Story < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :likes , dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users , through: :likes, source: :users
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Object Like:

```
class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :story_id, :user_id
 belongs_to :users
 belongs_to :story
end
```

Now

It's wrong to say that user has likes because the story has the likes and not the user.

I don't want to do:

```
user.likes
```

and the user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :avatar, :email

 has_many :stories
 #What am i missing here?
end
```

The question is how can i get the users who like the story?
I want to do something like:

s = Story.find(2)
s.likes.users

What am i missing here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in User

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :avatar, :email
  has_many :likes , dependent: :destroy
  has_many :stories,through: :likes
end
```

Comment: `s = Story.find(2)` & `s.users`